# Why Docker images aren't based on current GNU/Linux distribution

Tags: docker

I'm running [Docker CE](https://www.docker.com/community-edition) on CentOS 7 but when I bash into a container I can see it is based on Debian:

```
$ sudo docker exec -it 0123456789ab bash
# cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Is it possible to use a CentOS based image for the containers instead of Debian (e.g. to use commands like `visudo`)? Why this is not the default behavior since I'm using CentOS? Thank you.

Note, I installed [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#os-requirements) and [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/#master-builds), then I created a few images (Python, Postgres, Redis). I've never installed CentOS or Debian images. All the containers use a Debian release though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker images are not created based on your current running Linux distribution, but rather based on what the base image is defined in the Dockerfile. [Docker official images](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/official_repos/) provide Docker images based on different Operating Systems, so you'll have to pick an image based on the operating system